# OffsetDateTime to milliseconds

Tags: java, datetime, java-8

I want to know if there is a way to convert `java.time.OffsetDateTime` to Milliseconds, I found this way, but I don't know if it is the best one:

```
book.getInteractionDuration().getStartTimeStamp().toEpochSecond()*1000
```

Comment: Do you mean "to milliseconds since the Unix epoch"? I assume so, but I thought it worth checking before answering.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I would just convert the `OffsetDateTime` to an `Instant` and then use [`toEpochMilli`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toEpochMilli()):

```
long millis = book.getInteractionDuration().getStartTimeStamp().toInstant().toEpochMilli();
```

Unlike `toEpochSecond()`, this approach won't lose any more precision than is inherent in wanting milliseconds rather than nanoseconds.

Comment: but it gives millis in UTC (I need millis of current time zone)

Comment: @user924: Given that the answer was accepted, I don't believe that's what the questioner was looking for. I suggest you ask a new question explaining *why* you believe you want that - it's a pretty unusual requirement, which may have its background in a different problem.

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```java
long millis = offsetDateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
```